# how to find if push notification certification is wrong?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I want to know that how do i find that my push notification certificate is wrong.I am getting devicetoken on my device but doesn't getting any notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps described here, (or imlement a function for catching the error in your code) and read the eroor. The example code here will let you know if the certificates is wrong. The author also notes this in the article.

http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/